# Custom sort of multi-element nested list

Tags: javascript

I'd like to sort the following array using the first element in each sub-array:

```
lst = [[1, 2], [5, 4], [4, 9], [9, 1], [2,2]]
```

I would like to sort this list so that it looks like this:

```
srt_lst = [[1, 2], [2,2], [4, 9], [5, 4], [9, 1]];
```

How can I do this in pure javascript? (no external libs, underscore, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

The Array.sort method takes a compare function as an optional argument,

You can specify one like this:

`function compare(a, b) { .... }`

so using an anonymous function you could do it like this :

```
lst.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
    if (b[0] < a[0]) return 1;

    return 0;
});
```

Note : Although sort returns the sorted array, it also acts on the array you are running the method on, so if you need to keep the original `lst` array in tact and in original order, that is worth bearing in mind and you may have to make a clone before performing the sort operation.